# Stuck in the construction of a very simple function

Tags: coq

I am learning Coq. I am stuck on a quite silly problem (which has no motivation, it is really silly). I want to build a function from ]2,+oo] to the set of integers mapping x to x-3. That should be simple... In *any* language I know, it is simple. But not in Coq. First, I write (I explain with a lot of details so that someone can explain what I don't understand in the behaviour of Coq)

```
Definition f : forall n : nat, n > 2 -> nat.
```

I get a subgoal

```
  ============================
   forall n : nat, n > 2 -> nat
```

which means that Coq wants a map from a proof of n>2 to the set of integers. Fine. So I want to tell it that n = 3 + p for some integer p, and then return the integer p. I write :

```
intros n H.
```

And I get the context/subgoal

```
  n : nat
  H : n > 2
  ============================
   nat
```

Then i suppose that I have proved n = 3 + p for some integer p by

```
cut(exists p, 3 + p = n).
```

I get the context/subgoal

```
  n : nat
  H : n > 2
  ============================
   (exists p : nat, 3 + p = n) -> nat

subgoal 2 (ID 6) is:
 exists p : nat, 3 + p = n
```

I move the hypothesis in the context by

```
intro K.
```

I obtain:

```
  n : nat
  H : n > 2
  K : exists p : nat, 3 + p = n
  ============================
   nat

subgoal 2 (ID 6) is:
 exists p : nat, 3 + p = n
```

I will prove the existence of p later. Now I want to finish the proof by exact p. So i need first to do a

```
destruct K as (p,K).
```

and I obtain the error message

> Error: Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive
>   definition ex.

And I am stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are absolutely right! Writing this function *should* be easy in any reasonable programming language, and, fortunately, Coq is no exception.

In your case, it is much easier to define your function by simply *ignoring* the proof argument you are supplying:

```
Definition f (n : nat) : nat := n - 3.
```

You may then wonder "but wait a second, the natural numbers aren't closed under subtraction, so how can this make sense?". Well, in Coq, subtraction on the natural numbers isn't really subtraction: it is actually *truncated*. If you try to subtract, say, 3 from 2, you get 0 as an answer:

```
Goal 2 - 3 = 0. reflexivity. Qed.
```

What this means in practice is that you are always allowed to "subtract" two natural numbers and get a natural number back, but in order for this subtraction make sense, the first argument needs to be greater than the second. We then get lemmas such as the following (available in the [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Arith.Minus.html)):

```
le_plus_minus_r : forall n m, n <= m -> n + (m - n) = m
```

In most cases, working with a function that is partially correct, such as this definition of subtraction, is good enough. If you want, however, you can restrict the domain of `f` to make its properties more pleasant. I've taken the liberty of doing the following script with the [ssreflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/) library, which makes writing this kind of function easier:

```
Require Import Ssreflect.ssreflect Ssreflect.ssrfun Ssreflect.ssrbool.
Require Import Ssreflect.ssrnat Ssreflect.eqtype.

Definition f (n : {n | 2 < n}) : nat :=
  val n - 3.

Definition finv (m : nat) : {n | 2 < n} :=
  Sub (3 + m) erefl.

Lemma fK : cancel f finv.
Proof.
move=> [n Pn] /=; apply/val_inj=> /=.
by rewrite /f /= addnC subnK.
Qed.

Lemma finvK : cancel finv f.
Proof.
by move=> n; rewrite /finv /f /= addnC addnK.
Qed.
```

Now, `f` takes as an argument a natural number `n` that is greater than `2` (the `{x : T | P x}` form is syntax sugar for the `sig` type from the standard library, which is used for forming types that work like subsets). By restricting the argument type, we can write an inverse function `finv` that takes an arbitrary `nat` and returns another number that is greater than `2`. Then, we can prove lemmas `fK` and `finvK`, which assert that `fK` and `finvK` are inverses of each other.

On the definition of `f`, we use `val`, which is ssreflect's idiom for extracting the element out of a member of a type such as `{n | 2 < n}`. The `Sub` function on `finv` does the opposite, packaging a natural number `n` with a proof that `2 < n` and returning an element of `{n | 2 < n}`. Here, we rely crucially on the fact that the `<` is expressed in ssreflect as a boolean computation, so that Coq can use its computation rules to check that `erefl`, a proof of `true = true`, is also a valid proof of `2 < 3 + m`.

To conclude, the mysterious error message you got in the end has to do with Coq's rules governing computational types, with live in `Type`, and propositional types, which live in `Prop`. Coq's rules forbid you from using proofs of propositions to build elements that have computational content (such as natural numbers), except in very particular cases. If you wanted, you could still finish your definition by using `{p | 3 + p = n}` instead of `exists p, 3 + p = n` -- both mean the same thing, except the former lives in `Type` while the latter lives in `Prop`.

Comment: You probably mean {p | 3 + p = n} is a set ? I did not know that Coq's rules forbid from using proofs to get a computational content; i naively believed that that was the idea behind Coq. Anyway, thank you for your answer, I will re-read it as soon as I'll have a look on the ssreflect library (maybe next week).

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher a `Set` in Coq is just a special kind of `Type`. One of the reasons for controlling the interaction between `Type` and `Prop` is to make it possible to erase proofs when extracting a program.