# Can´t destruct exists in hypothesis

Tags: coq

Would anyone explain to me why the same tactics (destruct) applied to the same hypothesis (bijective f) works in the first lemma and not in the second? Also, what should I do in order to fix it? I guess it has to do with mixing Prop and Type in the statement of the second lemma, but I don´t understand exactly what is happening here. Thank you in advance.

```
Require Import Setoid.

Definition injective {A B: Type} (f: A->B) :=
forall x y: A, f x = f y -> x = y.

Definition bijective {A B: Type} (f: A->B) :=
exists g: B->A, (forall x: A, g (f x) = x) /\ (forall y: B, f (g y) = y).

Definition decidable (t: Type): Type:=
(forall x y: t, {x=y}+{x<>y}).

Lemma bijective_to_injective:
forall t1 t2: Type,
forall f: t1 -> t2,
bijective f -> injective f.
Proof.
intros t1 t2 f H1.
destruct H1 as [g [H1 H2]]. (* <--- WORKS HERE *)
intros x y H3.
rewrite <- H1.
rewrite <- H1 at 1.
rewrite H3.
reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma bijective_dec:
forall t1 t2: Type,
forall f: t1 -> t2,
bijective f ->
decidable t1 ->
decidable t2.
Proof.
intros t1 t2 f H1 H2 x y.
destruct H1 as [g [H1 H2]]. (* <--- DOESN´T WORK HERE *)
Qed.
```

Comment: Searching for your particular error message (`Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive definition ex`) helps a lot: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765188/)(your question imo is a duplicate of this one) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253726/). If you feel brave enough you might want to look also at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322979/) great question/answer pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed your problem is that you need a so-called "informative definition" for `bijective` that is to say, one where you can extract the actual witness such as:

```
{ g: B -> A | cancel f g /\ cancel g f }
```